# Pasting data from the clipboard to the excel cell using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have made a string which consists of ID's separated by new line feed character(\n). Now I want to paste this string into the excel so that all the ID's get pasted in different cells in a column.For all this I have populated the  string in $finCode which I have copied to the clipboard. Now I need to select a cell in the excel sheet and then paste the whole string on that cell so that all the ID's get populated in all the different cells of the excel in the same column.
The code is as  follows:

I am importing the workbook as:

```
$workbook = $xldoc.Workbooks.Open($testType)
```

I am checking for the worksheet to work on:

```
$mysheet = $workbook.worksheets | where {$_.name -eq "JPT"}
```

and I am using this $mysheet in the function as $currentSheet

Now the function is like:

```
addtitle()
{
$finCode=""

                         $fRow=$intRow


                         for($intRow = $fRow ; $intRow -le $maxRow ; $intRow++){

                            $codeName = $currentCode
                            $fin = $codeName + "_" + $i + "`n"
                            $finCode=$finCode+$fin


                            $i= $i + 1
                         }

                        # 

                        $currentSheet.Cells.Item($fRow,$currentCol).Value2  = $finCode

                         $clipboardData = $finCode

                         [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText($ClipboardData)



                         $currentSheet.Cells.Item($fRow,$currentCol).Select() | Out-Null

                         $currentSheet.Paste($finCode) | Out-Null

}
```

I am getting this error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
Please help me populate the values of the string in excel in different cells of the column.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest an alternative to copy/paste?

I have a script that generates a large Excel workbook and I previously used the copy/paste method because writing cell by cell was painfully slow, however then I ran into issues when trying to do anything else at the same time. If I used copy/paste in any other application at the same time, it would mess up my output.

I would recommend using a multi-dimensional array along with Value2 of the cell range.

Here is a generic example that you should be able to adapt to your needs:

```
# Open Excel
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
# Make Excel visible
$excel.Visible = $true
# Open new workbook
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
# Use first sheet
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
# Set a base string for the example
$baseString = "RowTextExample"
# Set column number
$columnNum = 1
# Set starting row number
$startRowNum = 1
# Set ending row number
$endRowNum = 10
# Create an empty multi-dimensional array that with the first digit equating to the number of rows and second equating to the number of columns
$multiArray = New-Object 'object[,]' $endRowNum, 1
# Since rows start at 1 and an array index starts at 0, set a variable to track the array index that starts at 0
$arrayIndex = 0
# Start at first row and go to the end row adding appending the base string with the row number
for($rowNum = $startRowNum; $rowNum -le $endRowNum ; $rowNum++)
{
    $multiArray[$arrayIndex, 0] = $baseString + "_$rowNum"
    $arrayIndex++
}
# Set the range where the data will be placed; the size must match the size of the multi-dimensional array
# Example using A1 format instead of column number: $range = $worksheet.Range("A$($startRowNum):A$endRowNum")
$range = $worksheet.Range($worksheet.Cells($startRowNum, $columnNum), $worksheet.Cells($endRowNum, $columnNum))
# Write the multi-dimensional to the range
$range.Value2 = $multiArray
```

Comment: Hi @Jon where should i mention the column no. in the range. For eg here its mentioned "A" . Now I have the column no like 3 to be populated , so how will I mention this in code (Range) function.

Comment: @shikher.mishra, OK I updated the code to reference the cell range using column numbers instead of the A1 format. I left the example of the A1 format just in case anyone else finds it useful.